# ODE Separable Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let $y = Φ(x)$ be a solution to $y' = y(5-y)(8-y)$ subject to $y(0) = 7$. Determine $\lim_{x \to ∞} Φ(x)$.

Workings:

I'm thinking I have to solve the differential equation.
$y' = y(5-y)(8-y) dy$

$y' = y(y-5)(y-8) dy$

$∫\frac{1}{(y-5)(y-8)y} dy = ∫1 dx$

$∫\frac{1}{(y-5)(y-8)y} dy$

$\frac{1}{(y-5)(y-8)y} = \frac{A}{(y-5)} + \frac{B}{(y-8)} + \frac{C}{y}$

Greatest Common Divisor gives:

$1 = Ay(y-8) + By(y-5) + C(y-5)(y-8)$

$y = 0:$

$1 = A(0)(0-8) + B(0)(0-5) + C(0-5)(0-8)$

$1 = 40C$

$C = \frac{1}{40}$

$y= 5:$

$1 = A(5)(5-8) + B(5)(5-5) + C(5-5)(5-8)$

$1 = -15A$

$A = \frac{-1}{15}$

$y = 8:$

$1 = C(8)(8-8) + B(8)(8-5) + C(8-5)(8-8)$

$1 = 24B$

$B = \frac{1}{24}$

$\frac{A}{(y-5)} + \frac{B}{y} + \frac{C}/{(y-8)}$

$= \frac{(-1/15)}{(y-5)} + \frac{(1/24)}{y} + \frac{(1/24)}{(y-8)}$

$= \frac{-1}{(15(y-5))} + \frac{1}{40y} + \frac{1}{(24(y-8))}$

$∫\frac{-1}{(15(y-5))} + \frac{1}{40y} + \frac{1}{(24(y-8))} dy$

$= \frac{-1}{15} \ln|y-5| + \frac{1}{40} \ln|y| + \frac{1}{24} \ln|y-8|$

$∫1 dx$

$= x + c$

$\frac{-1}{15} \ln|y-5| + \frac{1}{40} \ln|y| + \frac{1}{24} \ln|y-8| = x + c$

(I'm not too sure if I should solve for y here or not. There is another question later in the assignment where it states it can be expressed implicitly)

Letting $y(0) = 7$:

$\frac{-1}{15} \ln |(7)-5| + \frac{1}{40} \ln|(7)| + \frac{1}{24} \ln|(7)-8| = (0) + c$

$\frac{-1}{15} \ln|2| + \frac{1}{40} \ln|7| + \frac{1}{24} \ln|-1| = c$

$\frac{-1}{15} \ln|y-5| + \frac{1}{40} \ln|y| + \frac{1}{24} \ln|y-8| = x - 1/15 \ln|2| + 1/40 \ln|7| + 1/24 \ln |-1|$

I'm not sure if I did this correctly. Or what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to find the limit there is no need to solve the equation. look at the steady state solutions $y = 0, y = 5 y = 8.$ 
this is called the phase portrait:

(a) on  a number line mark these points.

(b) on each region bounded by these points, determine the sign of $y^\prime$ by evaluating $y^\prime$ at  a test point.

here is what it looks like for your problem:

sign of $y^\prime = y(5-y)(8-y):$  (-)     (+)        (-)         (+) from left to right.

$-\infty$--------<<--------0-------->>------5------<<---------8------>>---------$\infty$

if the initial $y$ value is $7,$ the solution will approach $5$ as $t \to \infty$ and $y \to 8$ as $t \to -\infty$
by uniqueness theorem for differential equation, the solutions may never reach, let alone cross these special solutions.

p.s. appreciate if anyone can augment this post with a line diagram.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. I had to solve the differential equation in another question anyways.

Comment: @hockeynl, you are welcome. hope this helps.

Comment: Sure you don't have this backwards?  If $y=7$, isn't $y'=-14$, meaning $y$ is decreasing?

Comment: @Mike, at $y = -\infty, y^\prime = -y^3 = \infty,$ then $y^\prime$ switches sign across every zero of $y^\prime.$ check it out again.

Comment: @Mike, you are right. i don't believe the number of arithmetical errors i make.